# How to change libvirt DHCP lease time

Tags: dhcp, libvirt, dnsmasq

I use QEMU KVM on my Ubuntu 16.04 server for managing virtual machines connected via both bridge and NAT.
I find that a VM connected via NAT requests DHCP request about every 20~25 minutes, and I want to change the DHCP lease (or request?) time longer.

The system log of the host machine is like this:

```
Oct 28 20:35:33 ubuntu dnsmasq-dhcp[1921]: DHCPREQUEST(virbr0) 192.168.122.174 52:54:00:8e:4d:a2
Oct 28 20:35:33 ubuntu dnsmasq-dhcp[1921]: DHCPACK(virbr0) 192.168.122.174 52:54:00:8e:4d:a2 cdsn-ns3-1
Oct 28 21:02:20 ubuntu dnsmasq-dhcp[1921]: DHCPREQUEST(virbr0) 192.168.122.174 52:54:00:8e:4d:a2
Oct 28 21:02:20 ubuntu dnsmasq-dhcp[1921]: DHCPACK(virbr0) 192.168.122.174 52:54:00:8e:4d:a2 cdsn-ns3-1
Oct 28 21:26:11 ubuntu dnsmasq-dhcp[1921]: DHCPREQUEST(virbr0) 192.168.122.174 52:54:00:8e:4d:a2
Oct 28 21:26:11 ubuntu dnsmasq-dhcp[1921]: DHCPACK(virbr0) 192.168.122.174 52:54:00:8e:4d:a2 cdsn-ns3-1
Oct 28 21:51:40 ubuntu dnsmasq-dhcp[1921]: DHCPREQUEST(virbr0) 192.168.122.174 52:54:00:8e:4d:a2
Oct 28 21:51:40 ubuntu dnsmasq-dhcp[1921]: DHCPACK(virbr0) 192.168.122.174 52:54:00:8e:4d:a2 cdsn-ns3-1
Oct 28 22:13:01 ubuntu dnsmasq-dhcp[1921]: DHCPREQUEST(virbr0) 192.168.122.174 52:54:00:8e:4d:a2
Oct 28 22:13:01 ubuntu dnsmasq-dhcp[1921]: DHCPACK(virbr0) 192.168.122.174 52:54:00:8e:4d:a2 cdsn-ns3-1
Oct 28 22:37:49 ubuntu dnsmasq-dhcp[1921]: DHCPREQUEST(virbr0) 192.168.122.174 52:54:00:8e:4d:a2
Oct 28 22:37:49 ubuntu dnsmasq-dhcp[1921]: DHCPACK(virbr0) 192.168.122.174 52:54:00:8e:4d:a2 cdsn-ns3-1
```

If libvirt would use something like isc-dhcp-server, I could manually set up the lease time, but I don't know where and how to change it for libvirt. Strangely, a status file "/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasqvirbr0.status" has a "expiry-time" field with a timestamp which is more than 1 hour away from the current time.

Why does the host machine shows DHCPREQUEST and DHCPACK so frequently? How can I change such frequent request interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently possible to configure the DHCP lease time for libvirt managed dnsmasq.

There are work in progress patches to add this feature though

https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2016-October/msg00561.html

which will hopefully get into a release soon.

Comment: Hi, I know this is a bit old. But I'm wondering how I could check the status of the request and the patch.

Comment: No files named `leasttime-*` in https://github.com/libvirt/libvirt/tree/master/tests/networkxml2confdata .

Answer (score 0):

I believe the accepted answer is no longer correct (i.e. the patch made it through, probably): see [this libvirt documentation](https://libvirt.org/formatnetwork.html).

Here's an example from the above documentation of setting `leasetime` for an entire range, or a specific host as identified by MAC:

```
<ip address="192.168.122.1" netmask="255.255.255.0" localPtr="yes">
  <dhcp>
    <range start="192.168.122.100" end="192.168.122.254">
      <lease expiry='1' unit='hours'/>
    </range>
    <host mac="00:16:3e:77:e2:ed" name="foo.example.com" ip="192.168.122.10">
      <lease expiry='30' unit='minutes'/>
    </host>
    <host mac="00:16:3e:3e:a9:1a" name="bar.example.com" ip="192.168.122.11"/>
  </dhcp>
</ip>
```